# File_exist returning false all the time on Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, file-exists

Im trying to check if a file exist on my /uploads folder of symfony 2.

```
    $file = $this->getAssetUrl('/uploads/hd/'.$gift->getImage());
     if(file_exists($file)) return $this->getAssetUrl('/uploads/hd/'.$gift->getImage());
     else return $this->getAssetUrl('/uploads/large/'.$gift->getImage());
```

This is always returning false, i debugged all the strings and the paths are correct, checked by hand that the file exist. Any ideas?

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($file)` ?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan string(30) "/uploads/hd/50f7d8c01f093.jpeg"

Comment: stupid suggestion but might make a difference. try: `$this->getAssetUrl('uploads/hd/'.$gift->getImage());` !!

Comment: No effect, I doutb is a problem of paths since I check that

Comment: I also checked with the complete non relative path manualy with file_check and it gave false again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getAssetUrl` will only print the URI of whatever resource it is you're printing, not the actual location.

If you placed your project at /var/www/myProject, the path `file_exists` expects is /var/www/myProject/web/uploads/hd/, but it will only get /uploads/hd. It'll look for a folder called "uploads" in your root directory. The first slash ("/") means "system root dir" for PHP, while it means "root URI" for your browser.

I believe `if (file_exists($this->get('request')->getBasePath() . "/uploads/hd/" . $gift->getImage()))` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! can you please elaborate your answer a bit more, how the file exist path should be then?

Comment: Just added that information. Please let me know if that works. If not, I'll figure a way.

Answer (score 0):

`getAssetUrl` is not returning a valid filename. It will give you a URL instead.

You must provide `file_exists` with a path (relative or absolute), so, you should use something like:

`$file = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'`
              `.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'` 
              `.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'uploads'`
              `.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'hd'`
              `.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$gift->getImage();`

Of course, adapt the path to your needs.